# dynamically added js file is not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I am having trouble to understand whats actually happening as I was able to successfully add the required file.

But unfortunately it is not working in IE and working on other browsers (opera, firefox, chrome).

Please see the code below. The file is getting added but not functioning in IE

```
if (typeof jQuery.ui === 'undefined') {
// UI loaded
//alert('no ui')
console.log('no ui');

var newJs4 = document.createElement('script');
newJs4.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
newJs4.setAttribute('src', 'https://visitrentals.com/js/jquery-ui.min-1.8.js');
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newJs4);
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]);
}
```

For better understand see the link below.

http://www.imagecreation.co.uk/WOE/WOETest2.html

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me, but not with the desired result.

At the moment when selectDate_horz-aff.js tries to access `$.datepicker`(and you receive the error) jQueryUI isn't loaded yet(note that when you use the DOM to inject the script it will be loaded asynchronously).

Possible  solutions:

- inject the selectDate_horz-aff.js also via the DOM , but only when `jQuery.ui` isn't undefined or when the load-event of the injected jQueryUI fires
- inject jQueryUI via document.write